# Need to Remove required field phone number from prestashop page using deliver.ee plugin

Tags: prestashop

For my eCommerce web page, i am using Deliver.ee for " Checkout payment" option.
But it is giving Error that,

"your shipping address does not have a phone number. You must enter at least one carrier to use this"

I need to remove the Phone number from the requirement field while Delivery.
Checked authentication.tpl file, but no success.

Please advice.

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: I am not able to find the file where i should change... as per my understanding, i should modify  class style from "required text" to "text" but not sure which file.... Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the "Client_has_phone" from delivereecarrier.php by making it true all time.